# Providing a download link to for a file to users - carrierwave and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have

```
<%= link_to "#{report.chapter_report_original_filename}", chapter_report_path(report) %>
```

in my view and

```
def show
  ...
  send_data @chapter_report.chapter_report.file
  ...
```

which happily creates a download for the user; unfortunately, the download is not the file, but some text about it. I'm guessing that I need to identify the particular bit of the Uploader record, but I don't know which - am I using the right approach, and what do I need to point it at?

Answer (score 0):

I found, after looking again at the Carrierwave docs at [rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Storage/Fog/File) that you can read the contents of the file with

```
send_data @chapter_report.chapter_report.read
```

... whether this is the best approach when taking into account threads etc. I have no  idea, but it's a start.